# How can I find the difference in hours between 2 times in character arrays?

Tags: matlab, date, time

I have 2 times stored in character arrays in MATLAB.

```
a = '11:00 PM'
b = '07:30 AM'
```

I want to find the difference in hours between the 2 times, which should be 8.5 hours in this example. Is there any short method to do that? I can `datenum` both numbers, subtract them, `datevec` the difference, extract the hours and minutes from the vector, and convert them into hours, but this takes a lot of lines. Is there a more efficient way of doing this or is there an existing function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by converting each string using [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html), taking the difference, then converting the result with [`hours`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hours.html):

```
numHours = hours(diff(datetime({a; b}, 'InputFormat', 'hh:mm a')));
numHours = numHours + 24.*(numHours < 0)

numHours =

    8.5000
```

The second line accounts for the condition in your example, where the second time has to occur on the *next day* for the time difference to be positive, so 24 hours are added to the (negative) difference.

Answer (score 0):

add a date to the time
like

```
a = '1/1/2000 11:00 PM'
b = '1/1/2000 07:30 AM'
```

the convert the string to datetime

```
x=str2num(strrep(a,':',''))
y=str2num(strrep(b,':',''))
```

then fine the difference between 2 dates

```
e = etime(x,y)
```

this will give you number of seconds between both times